# If a spacesuit cracks open, does the astronaut blow up due to difference of pressure?

Tags: pressure, air, space, explosions, aircraft

Me and my friends had a discussion on emergencies in outer space. One questioned what would happen if a spacesuit ruptured and exposed an astronaut to vaccuum. One claimed that since there is no external pressure in outer space to balance the internal pressure coming out of our body, it will expand until it cannot hold itself together and explode.

Another disagreed, saying that our body can adapt to the change of pressure as is the case with airplane doors opening midair or windows broken. He argued that the astronaut will instead die of suffocation due to the lack of air. Who is right?